# How do I get past the stealth part in the tutorial?

Tags: deus-ex

I have attempted to this many times, but I can barely make it halfway in the stealth course in the Deus-Ex: Game of the Year tutorial.

I have even tried throwing stuff around to distract the guards, but they seem to see me as soon as I reach the first junction (where you can see the alarm buttons on the walls left and right)

Do you have any tips for me?

Update: It seems there is a body armor near the beginning. Will it increase my chances if I wear it (if I ever will be able to wear it, of course)?

Comment: That stealth part is the reason I never played that game.  I had many friends tell me I was a moron for abandoning it early, but really the stealth part of the tutorial was terrible gameplay.

Comment: The other aspects of the game are pretty cool, though. I could almost say that it's the better Half-Life. Anyway, if I manage to get past it reproducibly, I'm going to go and put together a tutorial.

Comment: Putting the name of the game in your question would get more attention for it.

Comment: disagree about better HL.  DE lost me at first cut-scene, which HL just didn't do, and I love it for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems there is no reliable and reproducible way of getting past this. I did it on multiple occasions, where I threw things around and snuck past the guards behind their backs, the whole time crouching.

They sometimes detected me, and at other times just minded their own business.

At one time I took the left corridor, threw a small glass item to the right when I reached the mid part, then sprinted off to the finish. So stealth is not the only option here, and I think that's the message the game wants to deliver: there are always options.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a few tries and eventually made it by creating distractions tossing objects one way and going into a dark area in the other, by taking the second corridor right and not the first, and by using some luck.

Answer (score 1):

The body armor will greatly increase your chances of getting through the stealth course if you make mistakes. However, the stealth portion of the tutorial is very important considering you can't always go in with guns blazing to get past a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The game tells you how to pass this.  You stay out of the FOV of the soldiers, crouch to stay quiet and get behind cover when they pass.  It's hard to do it until you catch on, but then it gets real easy.  Just don't make any noise and don't be seen.  Useful skills for the game, too, since it helps incredibly when you can set up conditions to favor you when it comes to engagements.  Even sometimes I'll just ghost my way through Liberty Island just for something different.